# Greek grasshopper?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

What is this fearsome insect seen on a Greek Ionian island?

[image]

Comment: During which point in the day did you observe the cricket?

Answer (score 1):

That is in the family Tettigoniidae. It is a male. Species is *Eupholidoptera chabrieri* https://wikivisually.com/wiki/Eupholidoptera_chabrieri